# GCC -E preprocessor output

Tags: gcc, preprocessor

I am trying to preprocess a .h file and produce a new .h file with all of the # preproc directives resolved. I used `gcc -E file.c` command and I always get this output:

```
# 1 "file.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "file.c"
```

Which command should I use to produce a new preprocessed .h file?

Comment: So you say you really get these `>`?

Comment: `I always get this output:` That's great! This is a part of gcc correct output.  `Which command should I use to produce a new preprocessed .h file?` Use the one you are using right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

> -P
> Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers.

Simply use

```
gcc -E -P file.c
```

Comment: exactly what I am lookin for! thanks so much